# Logback - Logging multiple levels to a single file

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I want to write INFO, ERROR logs to a single log file. Below is my .log file but it writes only ERROR logs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE"
  ...

  <logger name="in.test" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="in.test" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="in.test" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense at all to define the same logger with different levels as you have done above. Please refer to the [logback architecture](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html) document to get a sense of how logback works.